# How to set environment variable to localhost?

Tags: java, python, jar, ubuntu-14.04, apache-tika

I have a very basic question regarding environment variables. The [Tika python library](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python#environment-variables) that I'm trying to work with mentioned the following:

> TIKA_SERVER_ENDPOINT: set to the host (local or remote) for the running Tika server jar

I downloaded the server `jar` from [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/tika/tika-server-1.15.jar) and ran it with `java -jar jarname.jar` I'm trying to set the environment variable to the localhost, but I'm not sure how exactly to do this. I tried the following:

```
TIKA_SERVER_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:9998
```

But this simply resulted in a `404`, with `Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname), Your host cannot be resolved by the DNS`,

I also ran `ps aux | grep java` to check if the `jar` file was running and saw that it was running on the port `9998`..... i.e:

```
java -cp /tmp/tika-server.jar org.apache.tika.server.TikaServerCLi -- port 9998 --host localhost
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here with my environment variable? I'm just very new to messing with `jar` files and environment variables, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by simply downloading the latest server jar from the [Apache downloads](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) page and then starting the server on my local machine from bash with:

```
java -jar tika-server -x.x.jar --port xxxx
```

Which started the tika server. I was then able to access tika in python through:

```
from tika import parser
parser.from_file('path_to_file')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe java is installed incorrectly. You can check java installation [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)

**Installation (with pip)**

```
pip install tika
```

**Installation (without pip)**

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

**Environment Variables**

These are read once, when tika/tika.py is initially loaded and used throughout after that.

`TIKA_VERSION` - set to the version string, e.g., 1.12 or default to current Tika version.
`TIKA_SERVER_JAR` - set to the full URL to the remote Tika server jar to download and cache.
`TIKA_SERVER_ENDPOINT` - set to the host (local or remote) for the running Tika server jar.
`TIKA_CLIENT_ONLY` - if set to True, then `TIKA_SERVER_JAR` is ignored, and relies on the value for `TIKA_SERVER_ENDPOINT` and treats Tika like a REST client.
`TIKA_TRANSLATOR` - set to the fully qualified class name (defaults to Lingo24) for the Tika translator implementation.
`TIKA_SERVER_CLASSPATH` - set to a string (delimited by ':' for each additional path) to prepend to the Tika server jar path.
`TIKA_LOG_PATH` - set to a directory with write permissions and the tika.log and tika-server.log files will be placed in this directory.

More information you can get [here](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's the link I've already been using. I just don't understand what I did wrong

Comment: Here is tutorial how to check java installation : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @ocean800 did you end up resolving this issue? I have the same question and this answer is not an answer is just a copy of the [README.md](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python)

Comment: @sAguinaga Nope sorry, I just gave up and didn't use this library